# How to use MediaStore data with OrmLite

Tags: android, audio, ormlite, mediastore

is it possible to use MediaStore data with OrmLite map for example MediaStore.Audio to object in java with OrmLite annotations or maybe it is already made ? Or maybe it is possible to get acces to this database and if it's possible what is the name of this database.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of MediaStore data?  Have you tried creating ORMLite entities for them?

Comment: I want to get albums, playlists etc. I know it could be done by making Cursor and get data in this way but I'm wondering if there is any way to do it faster and easier :).